# How to remove a cloned div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<div id="file">             
    <input type="file" name="txtImage[]" class="upload" />                                 
    <input type="text"  name="txtImageDesc[]" class="desc" />
</div>  
<input type="button" value="Add" name="addButton" id="addButton"  />
<input  type="button" value="Remove" name="removeButton" id="removeButton" />
```

This is my html div i need to add and remove on button click and here is my jquery code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#addButton').click(function(){
        $('.upload:last').clone().appendTo('#file');  
        $('.desc:last').clone().appendTo('#file');
    });

    $('#removeButton').click(function(){
        $('.upload:last').clone().remove('#file');
        $('.desc:last').clone().remove('#file');
    });
</script>
```

Problem is The On add button, it works perfectly but on remove button, it does not.
I need to remove the cloned div when i click on remove button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your remove code should be like this:

```
$('#removeButton').click(function(){
  $('#file > .upload:last').remove();
  $('#file > .desc:last').remove();
});
```

Comment: thanx.. one more thing i have htmk which also needs to be removed within it like:  $('#file > .<p><label>Upload Image</label>').remove();  it does not work..how will dis be done

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#removeButton').click(function(){
  $('.upload:last').remove();
  $('.desc:last').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this,

```
$('#removeButton').click(function(){
        $('#file').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: hide only those particular class, i.e. upload & desc